# Can't insert data into mysql from android application

Tags: php, android, mysql

I want to insert some data into the mysql database from my Android application but it doesn't work. I tried to insert data from the emulator and my mobile but there is nothing stored in the database. I don't know why. Could someone help me, please?
Here is my php code

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "food");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli-    >connect_error;
}
     echo "Connected to db";

$FOOD_ID =  isset($_POST['FOOD_ID']) ? $_POST['FOOD_ID'] : null;
$FOOD_NAME = isset($_POST['FOOD_NAME']) ? $_POST['FOOD_NAME'] : null;

mysql_query ("INSERT INTO food (FOOD_ID, FOOD_NAME) VALUES('$FOOD_ID', '$FOOD_NAME')");

?>
```

Here is the java code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String food_id;
String food_name;

private EditText name, id;
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cappuccino);

    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FOOD_ID);
    id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FOOD_NAME);


    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           food_id = name.getText().toString();
            food_name = id.getText().toString();

            new SummaryAsyncTask().execute((Void) null);
        }
    }); 
}

class SummaryAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private void postData(String idid, String namename) {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxxxxx/try.php");

        try {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ID", idid));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("NAME", namename));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        postData(food_name,food_id);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You have missed a closing single quote sign `'` for `'$FOOD_NAME`.

Comment: I have changed the php code but it still not work~

Comment: Have you tried posting the page from a browser to see if it works there? What errors are you getting after the query?

Comment: I think the php is work. I have posting the page to a browse. Then it show this line "Connected to db"

Comment: That just shows it connected, but you should check the results of the query as well.  After posting to the page, does the data appear in the database?

Comment: There is no data appear in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting values for **3** columns, but you have provided just **2** column names that's the reason your query ain't working.

See here

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO food (FOOD_ID, FOOD_NAME) VALUES('$FOOD_ID', '$FOOD_NAME,    NOW())");
                                ^//col1  ^//col2                                       //^val3 (where is its corresponding column name ?)
```

**Solution** : Provide the 3rd column name for `NOW()` and you will query work.

Secondly, you are using a deprecated database API i.e. **`mysql_*`** functions. You need to switch over to **`MySQLi`** or **`PDO`**.

Answer (score 0):

Column mismatched error, You need to replace/add `*TimeCoulmnname*` your table coulmn name

```
 mysql_query ("INSERT INTO food (FOOD_ID, FOOD_NAME, *TimeCoulmnname*) VALUES('$FOOD_ID', '$FOOD_NAME,    NOW())");
```

Note: Use PDO or Mysqli_* functions isnetad of mysql_* functions (deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

You are connecing to mySQL DB using "mysqli", but querying it through "mysql_query" function.
Try conncting using "mysqli"